# Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the coonvert function to run this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to return `datetime` variable from a stored procedure

```
RETURN @StatusCode                >returns string
IF(@LastConnected IS NOT NULL)  
RETURN @LastConnected             >returns datetime (Error!!) when
```

I removed this line and it executes perfectly

Comment: The return statement for an SP must return an int. Why are you trying to return a datetime - are you looking for an `OUTPUT` parameter?

Comment: Returning datetime is my requirements

Comment: So use an `OUTPUT` parameter - the return parameter is for returning a result indicating the success of failure of the SP. Returning data is done using an `OUTPUT` parameter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Use SELECT instead of RETURN

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetLastConnectedDate
--- INPUT PARAMETERS IF ANY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    ----- YOUR OTHER RELATED QUERIES

    IF(@LastConnected IS NOT NULL)  
            SELECT @LastConnected   ----- Use SELECT instead of RETURN here.

    RETURN @StatusCode
END
GO
```

Comment: For a single value `OUTPUT` is probably more appropriate.